# In prestashop 1.6.1.4,In prestashop, I am not able to get different id of same products varients i.e for 1kg,2kg,10kg

Tags: prestashop-1.6

Prestashop
In prestashop, I am not able to get different id of same products varients i.e for 1kg,2kg,10kg Oil.I need to compare the prices of these product varients with other stores product......pls help

Answer (score 0):

You must be talking about combination.
The combination IDs are stored in table "product_attribute".